# How do I handle multiple interactions that belong to specific users in Discord JS?

Tags: discord.js

How do I make it so that if 2 users execute a command that needs to detect if I press buttons, only that user can react to their own interaction, and if you press the others one, you will get an ephemeral message saying that it’s not yours?

I’ve thought of a solution, but I don’t know if it works:

Changing the filter in a collector.
Problem is, I don’t even know if it’s possible to change a filter, and if multiple people run that code at once, will the filter update to the most recent thing?

I know its a lot of questions, so the main question is just the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handle it is like this:

1. create a filter to include the ID's of the person/people you want to be able to use the button
2. create the interaction collector with that filter
   => The collector will only trigger for people you specified, everyone else will get a message saying that the interaction failed.

Alternatively, you could simply make a filter that collects all interactions, and then check for the ID of the person that interacted in the code.
If it's not someone that should be able to use the button, return an ephemeral message.

```js
//filters for only for interactions on a certain message and by a certain user
const filter = (interaction) => interaction.user.id == <userid> && interaction.message.id == <messageid>

//create a component collector for 5 minutes for that specific message or alternatively an entire channel (if you create it for a single message you don't need to check for the message ID in the filter)
const collector = <message/channel>.createMessageComponentCollector({filter: filter, time: 30000});

//when the filter collects something, this runs
collector.on('collect', async i => {
    //alternatively check for user IDs here
    if(interaction.user.id != <userid>) return <error message>

    //your code here
    ...
})

//this runs once the collector stops
collector.on('end', async collected => {...})
```